# Use jQuery/JS to determine the DAY OF WEEK

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Is there a method using either JavaScript or jQuery to determine what day of the week it is? For instance, if the date a user picks in the box is a Sunday, I can alert them.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
new Date().getDay();  //0=Sun, 1=Mon, ..., 6=Sat
```

See also: [Javascript Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) on MDN.

**Word of Caution:** This returns day of week on the browser. Because the earth is not flat, the day of the week for some users might be different from the day of the week for your server. This may or may not be relevant to your project...

If you are doing a lot of date work, you may want to look into JavaScript date libraries like [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) or [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: The "Javascript Date Object" page on MDN includes browser support (which in this case is excellent).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 24):

## Update

I just found my favorite method while adding the hacktastic bonus at the bottom.

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString('en', {weekday:'long'})
// returns "Thursday"
new Date().toLocaleDateString('en', {weekday:'short'})
// returns "Thu"
new Date().toLocaleDateString('es', {weekday:'long'})
// returns "jueves"
new Date().toLocaleDateString('es', {weekday:'short'})
// returns "jue."
new Date().toLocaleDateString('fr', {weekday:'long'})
// returns "jeudi"
new Date().toLocaleDateString('fr', {weekday:'short'})
// returns "jeu."
```

## Original Answer

If you only need this once in your page, keep it simple...

```
["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"][(new Date()).getDay()]
```

I didn't think it would be that big a deal to extend, but since I have 3 votes for internationalization in the comments...

```
// dictionary version
({
  es: ["Domingo", "Lunes",  "Martes",  "Miércoles", "Jueves",   "Viernes", "Sábado"],
  en: ["Sunday",  "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday",  "Saturday"]
})['en'][(new Date()).getDay()]
// returns "Wednesday"

// list version
langs=['en','es']

[
  ["Domingo", "Lunes",  "Martes",  "Miércoles", "Jueves",   "Viernes", "Sábado"],
  ["Sunday",  "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday",  "Saturday"]
][langs.indexOf('es')][(new Date()).getDay()]
// returns "Miércoles"
```

And finally, the code golf version...

```
["Sun","Mon","Tues","Wednes","Thurs","Fri","Satur"][(new Date()).getDay()]+"day"
```

Hacktastic Bonus...
If you only care about the abbreviation, you can trim everything else.

```
new String(new Date()).replace(/ .*/,'')

// or
(''+new Date()).split(' ')[0]

// or
Date().slice(0,3)
```

Comment: This same string can be placed into an underscore template, without the new Date() part, to conveniently format Date objects.  _.template(
            '<%= getMonth()+1 %>.<%= getDate() %>.<%= getFullYear() %> <%= ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"][getDay()] %>', someDateObject
        )

Comment: `["Sun","Mon","Tues","Wednes","Thurs","Fri","Satur"][(new Date()).getDay()]+"day"` Since all 7 stings end with the same 3 letters, you can extract them rather than repeating them.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky that kind of "clever" optimization will drive someone ***crazy*** if you ever want to internationalize your app...

Answer (score 9):

```
today = new Date()
dayIndex = today.getDay()
```

... will get you a numeric representation of "today".

```
0 = Sunday
1 = Monday
2 = Tuesday
3 = Wednesday
4 = Thursday
5 = Friday
6 = Saturday
```

Comment: Zero is Sunday :) Because it's a language from the US. In Europe it would make more sense to have monday as zero, but that's not the case here.

Answer (score 7):

A clearer and more detailed answer:

```
var days = [
    'SUN', //Sunday starts at 0
    'MON',
    'TUE',
    'WED',
    'THU',
    'FRI',
    'SAT'
];

d = new Date(); //This returns Wed Apr 02 2014 17:28:55 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)
x = d.getDay(); //This returns a number, starting with 0 for Sunday

alert (days[x]);
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geoyws/LBt2b/).

Answer (score 2):

If you need a lot of date handling, take a look at [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

send date and you will get position of the same day of that month . i.e. 15/02/2018 is Third Thursday.

```
 /*return day postion and dayname */
    function weekAndDay(date) {
        var arrayWeek =[];
        var date = new Date(date),
        days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'],
        prefixes = ['','First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth'];
        if (date.getDate() % 7 == 0) {
            var prefixes2 = date.getDate() / 7;
        }else{
            var prefixes2 = Math.ceil(date.getDate() / 7);
        }
        arrayWeek.push({
            'dayPos' : prefixes[prefixes2] ,
            'dayName' : days[date.getDay()]
        });
        return arrayWeek;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add some explenation to your answer? Only showing code can be confusing.