# jQuery Datepicker (Find if Monday, Tuesday, etc)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way where I could determine if a day is Monday, Tuesday, etc. using the current date?

Comment: The day will be shown in jQuery datepicker by default right?

Comment: You can see this post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174300/use-jquery-js-to-determine-the-day-of-week

Comment: Question alredy answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495644/how-to-get-the-day-from-a-particular-date-using-javascript

Comment: thank you for the replies.. I didn't notice that they are just the same. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var day = new Date('12/03/2012').getDay();
```

Starts from sunday

Comment: Thank you! I've always thought that getDay is something else. :)

Comment: $dt = new DateTime('2014-07-26');
echo $dt->format('l'); // Saturday