# Get all weekdays of a month when choosing month from jquery ui calender

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I want to get all weekdays of a month when choosing a month from Jquery UI calendar.

Here is the code that which select from date to To date, But I need, when I am selecting a month it should print all weekdays name of the whole month.

```
eg: monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday
    monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday
    monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday
    monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday
```

From start date date of a selected month to end month.

```html
<input id="from" />
<input id="to" />
<button id="getBetween">Get Between Dates</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

```js
$("#from").datepicker();
$("#to").datepicker();    

$('#getBetween').on('click', function () {
    var start = $("#from").datepicker("getDate"),
        end = $("#to").datepicker("getDate"),
        currentDate = new Date(start),
        between = []
    ;

    while (currentDate <= end) {
        between.push(new Date(currentDate));
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
    }

    $('#results').html(between.join('<br> '));
});
```

Comment: I edit the title for better understanding what you want... you might above the edit, so you don't get further negative votes. Also check my new answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45861167/3001970 and make it as correct if it suit you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet will list all the days of the selected date range. I've removed the datepicker references for the snippet. What isn't clear from your question is if the day names should be broken up into weeks or not.

```js
function getDayName(date) {
  var dayNames = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];
  
  return dayNames[date.getDay()];
}


$('#getBetween').on('click', function () {
    var start = new Date($("#from").val()),
        end = new Date($("#to").val()),
        between = [];

    while (start <= end) {
        between.push(getDayName(start));
        start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
    }

    $('#results').html(between.join('<br> '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
from start date date of a selected month to end month.

<input id="from" value="2017-08-01"/>
<input id="to" value="2017-08-31"/>
<button id="getBetween">Get Between Dates</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: hi Thijs thx for your response but need just selecting one date picker  NOT FROM TO TO DATE.

Comment: Thx for your response

Comment: Sorry to hear it is not the solution you're looking for. I guess the problem you're having is not clear to me. I hope someone else will be able to help you.

Comment: i need to select a month that should print days of all weeks in that month thx

Comment: not date picker i need month picker, when i select a month then it should prints,any way thx for your response

Comment: This answer was correct for the first way the question was asked. But I can be also found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174300/use-jquery-js-to-determine-the-day-of-week

Answer (score 1):

Here may edited answer after checking the comments on [@Thuhs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45861039/3001970) answer. Here a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wittich/3vkywLym/).

The idea is to get the weekday by `getDay()` and return that value from a array with the names of the week. The little plugin [**`moonth-picker`**](https://kidsysco.github.io/jquery-ui-month-picker/) returns the first day of the month. The function `new Date(selectedDate.getFullYear(), selectedDate.getMonth() + 1, 0, 23, 59, 59)` calutlates the last day.

```js
$("#InlineMenu").MonthPicker({
    // SelectedMonth: '04/' + new Date().getFullYear(),
    OnAfterChooseMonth: function(selectedDate) {
     
       var currentDate = selectedDate,     
            lastDayOfMonth = new Date(selectedDate.getFullYear(), selectedDate.getMonth() + 1, 0, 23, 59, 59),         
            weekdays = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"],
            between = [];
    
        while (currentDate <= lastDayOfMonth) {
            between.push(weekdays[new Date(currentDate).getDay()]);
            currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
        }
        
        $('#results').html(between.join(', '));
        
    }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//rawgit.com/KidSysco/jquery-ui-month-picker/v3.0.0/demo/MonthPicker.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//rawgit.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/dist/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//rawgit.com/KidSysco/jquery-ui-month-picker/v3.0.0/demo/MonthPicker.min.js"></script>

<div id='InlineMenu' style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;"></div>
<div id="results" style="padding: 20px;"></div>
```

Comment: Hi sorry for wrong comment i mentioned ,not date picker i need month picker, when i select a month then it should prints,any way thx for your response

Comment: @Praveen I edit the answer... is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Pls up vote and accept the answer as correct (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/318426)!