# Get last 7 days by names javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, names, days

How to get the last seven days, from today, (by names) in java script.
like if today is Wednesday, I want to get it like (Wednesday, Tuesday, Monday, Sunday, Saturday, Friday, Thursday, Wednesday).

Comment: Please may you edit the question to include a text-based [mcve]

Comment: start with this simple exercise: given an array `[1,2,3,4,5]`, use the `slice` method to produce  `[3,4,5,1,2]`.

Comment: Being picky: your last 7 days example shows 8 days

Comment: Get day of week: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174300/use-jquery-js-to-determine-the-day-of-week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the days in the string array and iterate them backward by getting current date with **new Date()** this will return the index of current day

```js
const weekday = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

const d = new Date();
let day = weekday[d.getDay()];

var wanteddays = 8;
var temp = d.getDay()
while(wanteddays!=0){
    if (temp <0)
    temp = 6;
    console.log(weekday[temp]);
    temp = temp-1;
    wanteddays = wanteddays -1;
}
```

Comment: Please cosider always leaving a comment or explanation to why your solution solves / help the OP.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen acknowledged

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDayName(date, len, local) {
  let newDate = new Date(date);
  let weekDays = [];

  Array(len).fill(1).forEach((subDay) => {
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() - subDay);
    weekDays.push(newDate.toLocaleDateString(local, { weekday: 'long' }));
  })
  return weekDays;
}
```

to use:

```
getDayName(Date.now(), 7, 'en-EN') 
OR
getDayName('10/12/2022', 7, 'en-EN')
```

Typescript:

```
function getDayName(date: Date | string | number, len: number, local:string) {
  let newDate = new Date(date);
  let weekDays: string[] = [];

  Array(len).fill(1).forEach((subDay: number) => {
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() - subDay);
    weekDays.push(newDate.toLocaleDateString(local, { weekday: 'long' }));
  })
  return weekDays;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should order an array to follow your wished output.

```js
    var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    var currentDay = days[ (new Date()).getDay()]
    days =  days.reverse();
    var x = days.indexOf(currentDay)
    var daysLastSeven =  days.slice(x).concat(days.slice(0,x))

    console.log(daysLastSeven)
```